# Fusion of transparent layer on to existing layer

Tags: color, print-design, layers, transparency

I have a layer with multiple shapes and colors, and I would like to manipulate the layer esaily by changing the intensity of the colors.

I know this can be easily achieved by an extra layer of the same shape silhouette and by selecting a color and changing the opacity. But that extra layer seems somewhat unprofessional. And because my layer has so many shapes, paths and colors... it is simply too tedious to replace each and every color.

So, can it be done without an extra transparency layer?

Comment: I would recommend [clipping masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/revealing-layers-clipping-masks.html) or [adjustment layers](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjustment-fill-layers.html).

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: I'm using Adobe Illustrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an adjustment layer (such as Levels) and play with the handles to manipulate the the intensity of the colors.